# Specifying of full namespace in function return type

Tags: c++, namespaces, return-type

I have the following code.

Header file `myclass.h`:

```cpp
namespace A::B
{
    template<typename Type, unsigned int Count>
    class MyClass
    {
        public:
            MyClass() = delete;
            Type getValue();
            explicit operator Type() noexcept;
        
        private:
            struct Impl;
            Impl* impl() const noexcept;
    };
}
```

Header file `myclassImpl.h`:

```cpp
#include "myclass.h"

namespace A::B
{
    template<typename Type, unsigned int Count>
    struct MyClass<Type, Count>::Impl
    {
        ...
    };
}
```

File `myclass.cpp`:

```
#include "myclass.h"
#include "myclassImpl.h"

using namespace A::B;

template<typename Type, unsigned int Count>
MyClass<Type, Count>::Impl* MyClass<Type, Count>::impl() const noexcept
{
    return static_cast<MyClass<Type, Count>::Impl*>(m_impl.get());
}

template class MyClass<int, 1>;
template class MyClass<float, 2>;
template class MyClass<double, 3>;
```

I receive the following error in Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 17.5.3:

```
syntax error: '*' was unexpected here
'A::B::MyClass': use of class template requires template argument list
'A::B::MyClass<Type,Count>::impl': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
```

The following also doesn't work:

```cpp
#include "myclass.h"
#include "myclassImpl.h"

namespace A {
namespace B {

template<typename Type, unsigned int Count>
MyClass<Type, Count>::Impl* MyClass<Type, Count>::impl() const noexcept
{
    return static_cast<MyClass<Type, Count>::Impl*>(m_impl.get());
}

}
}
```

But, if I add namespace `A::B` to the return type, then the error is gone:

```cpp
template<typename Type, unsigned int Count>
A::B::MyClass<Type, Count>::Impl* MyClass<Type, Count>::impl() const noexcept
{
    return static_cast<MyClass<Type, Count>::Impl*>(m_impl.get());
}
```

**Can you please explain, why do I need to specify the full namespace in the return type of the function?**

Comment: You shouldn't need to, but compilers have bugs, especially when it comes to relatively new features. I suggest sticking `typename` in front of `MyClass<Type, Count>::Impl*`, this is how it used to be before c++20 and it works everywhere. Your original version works with gcc and clang 16 as is, but not in MSVC, presumably because of the bug.  Your "fixed" (redundant) version works in MSVC but not in clang 15 because clang 15 doesn't seem to implement the relevant portion of C++20 yet.

Comment: [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TqMfezsjT)

Comment: Wow, thank you for your answer. I haven't known that it's a new feature. `typename` here is needed, because Impl is dependent on MyClass type, am I right?

Comment: `typename` is needed in C++17, but not in C+20 (because it is a type-only context, a new feature of C++20).

Comment: @Eugene: `typeename` is needed because `Impl` is dependent on the template arguments of `MyClass`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/